# Scaling ADC in Pic 16F Micro (asm)

Tags: assembly, pic

I have an ADC working with a PIC16F676 (I appreciate there are probably better chips around to do this but the design is currently stable) and MC9700A temperature sensor.

At present it outputs the ADC value on PORT C (I am only using 6 bits)

```
 movwf     ADC_VALUE
     rrf       ADC_VALUE        ; 4 x Divide (1.5Vref (AN1) & 1.5V IP (AN3) = all 6 bits on)
     bcf       STATUS,C         ; Limits Digitiser Tag with MCP9700A -40C to +97C

 movf      ADC_VALUE,w
     movwf     PORTC          ; Copy the ADC value to PORTC
```

Instead of outputting the 'raw' value I want to convert that to degrees C. I know that `temperature = (ADC_VALUE*5.0)/10.24` would achieve this in C but what is the equivalent in asm (I would prefer to stick with asm as this project took a while to achieve)?

Lastly before outputting the value on port C I want to 'strip out' all negative temperature values (-40C to -1C) and only output 1C to 97C. As I am only using 6 output pins I appreciate that this will max out at 63C but that is fine.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Regards
Active

Comment: *5 / 10.24 is VERY close to / 2 (which can be done in ASM with a simple right-shift) ... how precise are these measurements? are 2.5% off acceptable ?

Comment: Yes, the MCP9700 is only +/-2C anyway. I may use a more accurate device later buts that's for another day. How can I then strip off the negative values before output?

Comment: is it 2 complement numbers? if you just want to remove the sign, afair it's "when the top bit is set (check with 'and 0x80'), `p = not (n-1)`"

Comment: Thanks again, after 'conversion' the output on PORT C would somehow be -40C to +97C (expressed as / limited to 6 bit binary), I don't want the -40C to -1C values to output. Please elaborate more on the asm to achieve this (I am a newbie).

Comment: Then you need a branch, where you test the registers top bit, and skip a 'set register to 0' if it's not. every value that does have the bit set will be set to zero  (BTFSC should do)

Comment: In hindsight I probably phrased my question wrongly, as I only have 6 bits of output available I need to 'scale' the ADC so it only outputs values after conversion between 294 and 1023 (and not less than 294) which represents 1C to 97C  temperature

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159467/discussion-between-tommylee2k-and-active).